# Why matplotlib.pyplot.imshow does not show colors correctly?

Tags: matplotlib, imshow

Why colors are not accurate when using numpy arrays as inputs for `imshow()`?, I was expecting a pure blue, but I see in a color picker there is a value of 55 in red (scale 0..255), why is this?

[image: matplotlib.pyplot.imshow]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I get a completely blue image as expected.

Comment: Color component values must be in the range 0-1.  Try again with `p1=np.array([[[0, 0, 255]]])/255.0`.

Comment: yeah, already tried with 0.0..1.0, using 0, 255 range for example